# android:persistent="true" can this piece of code make my app running in background even user clear running apps?

Tags: android

I want my app to be running even when the user clears the running app. Can I use this:

```
android:persistent="true"
```

or should I go for a `service` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android:persistent
>
> Whether or not the application should remain running at all times —
>   "true" if it should, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".
>   Applications should not normally set this flag; persistence mode is
>   intended only for certain system applications.

You should not use this flag. Go for a `Service` instead.